# Jenkins Pipeline - conditional execution with branch and 1 other parameter (manual)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We are deploying our application using Jenkins pipeline like this -

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build For Production') {
        when { branch 'development' }
        steps {
             sh './bin/build.sh'
        }
    }
    stage('Build For Production') {
        when { branch 'master' }
        steps {
             sh './bin/copy_needed_auth.sh'
             sh './bin/build.sh'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

When a developer pushes code on bitbucket, The application is deployed automatically. Using branch, we set our deployment strategy.

```
when { branch 'master' }
```

But we need to set a manual chacking for deploying on production (master branch) like - when a developer will merge code in the master branch, he will also set some tag or something like that so that Jenkins pipeline will check branch + other manual logic to deploy in production.

we are doing like this -

```
when { 
    branch 'master' 
    tag: 'release-*'
}
```

But it's not working. Is there any other strategy to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, you could try to tag by using environment variables. Maybe something defined in the environment {} directive within the stage. E. g.

`$PROD = xyz_prod`

Then,

`when {  branch 'master'  tag: $PROD }`

Not sure why your approach failed, but building tags on a script using variables could do the trick.